# Move biblatex label into margin

Tags: biblatex, indentation, margins

I'm trying to move everything nonessential into the margins. But I couldn't find how BibLaTeX generates the entries' labels (like `[1]` generated by `\cite` and in front of the item in the list, don't know the exact term).

I want these labels in the margin (by surrounding them with `\llap`).

Inserting the following after `\usepackage{biblatex}` just lets the labels disappear:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\list{%
    \llap{here}%
    \hspace{0.5em}%
}{%
    \setlength\leftmargin{0pt}%
}}{\endlist}{\item}
```

What code do I have to insert `here` to print the label? (Regardless of the style, this should work with `style=alphabetic` and `style=numeric` for example)

(complete example seems like overkill?)

[image: Intended result at the bottom]

Here, the `[1]` is hardcoded.

Answer (score 5):

Each style loads its `.bbx` file which defines its own bibliography (bib)environment, so I think that a solution working for all the styles it's not easy to achieve. In the case of the `numeric` style, you could define (in the preamble of your document) the `bibliography` (bib)environment like this:

```
\makeatletter
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
{\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
\makeatother
```

Comment: didn't think of that… I actually wanted something that would work with any style (since it's only layout) though. But I found the bbx'es now, it seems they just use `\defbibenvironment`, too, piecing together the label there. I thought there was a common macro…