# Left-margin alignment of biblatex's bibliography list

Tags: biblatex, indentation, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move biblatex label into margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23862/move-biblatex-label-into-margin)

Is there a simple solution to force the numerals of `biblatex`'s bibliography list (via `\printbibliography`) into the left column such that text of the entry will align with the rest of the text in the document?

I'd like to produce

```
   References
1. Last, F. M.; Last, F. M., Title; Publisher: City, Year, pages.
2. Last, F. M.; Last, F. M., Title; Publisher: City, Year, pages.
```

instead of the usual

```
References
1. Last, F. M.; Last, F. M., Title; Publisher: City, Year, pages.
1. Last, F. M.; Last, F. M., Title; Publisher: City, Year, pages.
```

It seems that using the solution from my earlier question "[How can I align section titles and list environments in the left margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/how-can-i-align-section-titles-and-list-environments-in-the-left-margin)" does not work, so I'm assuming that generating the bibliography list goes beyond declaring a simple enumerate list.

Comment: This question has mostly been answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23862). To omit square brackets around the label numbers you'd use `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on which bibliography style you are using for `biblatex`; in this case it looks like you're thinking of `numeric`, so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% from biblatex

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}% forgot this; from Audrey's comment 

% default bibliography environment (from biblatex.sty)
\defbibenvironment{bibliography} 
  {\list{}{%
     \leftmargin\bibhang 
     \itemindent-\leftmargin 
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
      \parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% 'numeric' bibliography environment (from numeric.bbx)
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
%      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-\labelsep}% <-- changed
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}

\nocite{companion,cotton,gonzalez,hammond,iliad,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,
  knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:c, knuth:ct:d, knuth:ct:e}%
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```